# How do you clone elements in a Map

Tags: java

```
private static Map<Integer, String> choices = new HashMap<Integer, String>(3);
// choices get populated here
```

What is the simplest way to clone elements in a Map to a different structure.

Comment: What's the other data structure you want to copy to? Another map?

Comment: what are you trying to do specifically?  Create a new map with copies of the *references* to the objects in the original?  Or create a new map with *copies* of the *objects themselves*.  very different things.

Comment: Yes copy them into another Map and would like to clone all elements within the Map itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your use of "clone" I assume you're trying to copy the elements to another map.  You can do that easily:

```
Map<...> myMap;

Map<...> newMap = new HashMap<...>(myMap);

//or

Map<...> newMap;
newMap.putAll(myMap);
```

Comment: I was wondering if there was a helper function somewhere in the commons-lang library which did something similar. I thought this should have been straightforward and simpler, but I guess this approach is fine

Answer (score 2):

For your case, since Integers and Strings  are immutable, you can do what Mark said.  This works because you can not modify the Integers/Strings once they are created.

In the general case though, where you do not have immutable object, you need to understand very clearly what you are trying to do.  There are two possibilities, and each will have drastically different consequences.

The first is that you want to create a new Map that contains equivalent references to the objects in the first Map.  If you go this route, both Maps will contain references that point to the *same* underlying objects.  i.e. if you pull an object out of either Map and modify it, the change will be reflected in the other collection, because both Maps contain references to the same objects.  If you want to go this route, @Mark provided a good answer.

The second is that you want to create a new Map that contains references to *copies* of the objects in the first Map.  In this case, you actually need to create a new Object for every Object in the first Map.  You can add a `copy()` method to the class definitions, or you can create a 'copy constructor' on the class.  This is a constructor that takes a reference to an Object of its type and creates a duplicate of the argument.  Since you are copying the objects themselves, then modifying the object in a Map will not affect the objects in the other Map.  Note that if your objects in turn have references to other objects, you need to copy those too.

These choices exist because in Java, when you do `Object obj = new Object()`, 'obj' is a *reference* to the thing you just created.  If you then do `Object obj2 = obj` you have 2 references to the same underlying Object.  Invoking methods or changing properties on either reference affects the same object.

When you go with the first approach, you end up with different references in each map (because java is always pass by value, which means that the reference values are copied), but those different references still have the same value, so they point to the same underlying object.

Comment: I guess in this case Mark's solution will work because both Integer and String are immutable but otherwise individual elements have to be cloned (somehow) and added to new map.

Comment: @bala you are correct.  Let me modify my answer so I dont have to waste all that effort ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how deep you want to clone. If your keys and values are serializable then you can deserialize and serialize again. Otherwise, the alternative is to do manually.

Comment: a shallow clone in this case is just as good as a completely deep clone, as Integer and String are immutable.